# how to configure live video streaming android mobile to wowza media server?

Tags: android, video, streaming, wowza

I installed and configure wowza media server for live video streaming but i can't do live video streaming in wowza server.And i need to live video streaming android mobile to wowza server. Please please can you tel me how to configure mobile video streaming to server step by step.

And which IP Address i give in "BIND IP ADDRESS & CONNECTION IP ADDRESS & ORIGIN IP ADDRESS"

All ideas are welcome.Please help me am eagerly wait for solution..

thank you so much
Regards
Ragav.G

Answer (score 1):

Here is the step to configure live streaming in wowza server : http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?36

Here is the list of encoders to stream android to wowza server

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.org.gregoire.mobile.BroadcasterPro
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Streambox.MobileEncoder&feature=search_result
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tv.wpn.biokoda.android.emitfree&hl=en

Hope this helps to you